# Searching for string in memory causes to crash

Tags: c++, memory

I am not so good with C++, but I am experiencing issues scanning for a string in my own memory.

Here's a small sample of my code:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0x400000; i < 0xFFFFFFFFFF; i++) {
    string s = (char *) i;
    if (s[0] == 'H') {
        if (s == "Hello") {
            cout << "Found at address: " << i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps scanning until it comes to a certain "position" where the application crashes. I am guessing it is reaching unallocated memory and is crashing due to undefined behavior.

But the question is, what's the best way to do this? I'm trying to stay away from ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory.

**In general:**
What's the best way to search for a string within its own process?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This `string s = (char *) i;` will already lead to undefined behaviour. `i` isn't a null-terminated string.

Comment: Yes I realized that, but the question is how may I be able to fix it? Or any other way to prevent it from crashing?

Comment: `VirtualQuery` can tell you which regions of address space are backed by actual memory. Or, you can probe with `IsBadReadPtr`. Or, you can go ahead and access the memory under a `__try/__except` block, and handle SEH exceptions appropriately.

Comment: I thank you for the help @IgorTandetnik, I searched and still have no idea how to use VQ - for IsBadReadPtr, how can this work? Isn't the crash source from (char *) i in general? I'd need to pass it this pointer which would be pointless, right? The compiler kept telling me that I need a catch before the __except, yet when I add one, it says that __except is not defined in the scope.

Comment: The `string` is unnecessary and may try to allocate arbitrary amounts of memory - `char* s = (char*)i; if (*s == 'H') ...`.

Comment: No, the `(char*)i` cast by itself doesn't cause the crash. Attempting to construct an `std::string` from the resulting pointer does (because the constructor attempts to read the memory pointed to). Drop `std::string`, use plain `char*` pointers and C-style comparisons (see e.g. `memcmp`)

Comment: I am not really sure if it isn't, because in C# this dramatically fastens the scan, comparing two strings is really heavy work there - whereas checking the first 2 characters would narrow it down - are you sure we don't need it here?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: [IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx).

Comment: Alright, so I added if (IsBadReadPtr((char* )i, 1)) continue; - Now it just stops at a certain address (doesn't crash), for example it stops at i = 4256381 to be exact. NEVERMIND - issue was on my side, had to create it in a new thread.

Comment: So apparently creating a new thread does not let me access the memory - Any idea if VirtualQuery would fix?

Comment: Thank you Igor, your version worked - though it is really slow. Please post your solution of IsBadReadPtr so I can select it as correct answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Deferencing arbitrary pointer values (addresses) is undefined behavior and varies by platform and operating system.

Crashing is one of many undefined behaviors.

Comment: I have already stated that in the Original Question, I'm just wondering if it's possible to prevent the crash or at-least another way to do it.

Comment: It depends on the platform and operating system, there is no universal way.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not mentioned in the tags, based on the mention of `ReadProcessMemory`, I'm going to assume you want this for Windows.

To do this in Windows, you pretty much need to use `VirtualQuery` to figure out what parts of your address space are usable (particularly important on 64-bit systems, where valid addresses are much sparser than on 32-bit systems).

Code using VirtualQuery to find searchable blocks could look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <class InIter1, class InIter2, class OutIter>
void find_all(InIter1 buf_begin, InIter1 buf_end, InIter2 pat_begin, InIter2 pat_end, OutIter output) { 
    for (auto pos = buf_begin;
        buf_end != (pos = std::search(pos, buf_end, pat_begin, pat_end));
        ++pos)
    {
        *output++ = (void *)pos;
    }
}

template <class outIter>
void find_locs(std::string const &pat, outIter output) {

    unsigned char *p;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;

    for ( p = nullptr;
        VirtualQuery(p, &info, sizeof(info)) == sizeof(info);
        p += info.RegionSize ) 
    {
        if (info.State == MEM_COMMIT && 
           (info.Type == MEM_MAPPED || info.Type == MEM_PRIVATE)) 
        {
            find_all(p, p + info.RegionSize, pat.begin(), pat.end(), output);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <pattern>", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    find_locs(argv[1], std::ostream_iterator<void *>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Expect this to turn up a few "spurious" matches. In particular, even if the string you search for doesn't occur anywhere else in the process' memory space, there will be one copy as part of `argv` and (at least) one more for the temporary `std::string` that's passed to `find_locs`, so expect a bare minimum of two matches for any string you might pass.

You'll probably also want to read through the docs for `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`. I've chosen a subset of blocks that (I'm pretty sure) is safe to read (i.e., those that are committed and either mapped or private) but depending on what you're looking for, you might want to change that to restrict it to searching only through program text rather than text and data.

Comment: What are the parameters that needs to get passed? I see there's a "pattern" there?

Comment: @John: As it stands right now, you run it like: `search "my_string"`. Despite the "pattern", it really only searches for literal matches.